# JavaFX: how to assign different colors to different TreeItems?

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have read here and elsewhere that one should use `CellFactory`, but I can't seem to understand how. I am not after setGraphic, I just want to use css to define different colors to different nodes depending on their type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Your style classes: obviously choose names that logically reflect your application
List<String> allTreeItemStyles = Arrays.asList("style1", "style2", "style3"); 

TreeView<MyTreeType> tree = new TreeView<>();
tree.setCellFactory(tv ->  new TreeCell<MyTreeType>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyTreeType item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        getStyleClass().removeAll(allTreeItemStyles);
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(...); // appropriate text for item
            String styleClass = ... ; // choose style class for item
            getStyleClass().add(styleClass);
        }
    }
});
```

If for some reason you are still stuck using JavaFX 2.2, you need to replace the lambda expression with an anonymous inner class:

```
tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<MyTreeType>, TreeCell<MyTreeType>>() {
    @Override
    public TreeCell<MyTreeType> call(TreeView<MyTreeType> tv) {
        return new TreeCell<MyTreeType>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyTreeType item, boolean empty) {
                 // implementation as above...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then in an external style sheet, just do

```
.tree-cell.style1 {
   /* ... */
}

.tree-cell.style2 {
  /* ... */
}

/* etc */
```

(Note there is no space between `.tree-cell` and `.style1`.)

Comment: how do you do it in java 7?

Comment: Updated to show. Just turn the lambda into an anonymous inner class.

Comment: In JavaFX 2 they did not exist yet, but in JavaFX 8, you as well can use PseudoClasses if the style reflects a different state of the items (as opposed to a different kind).

Comment: How to append also the Graphic  :)  [ The default one that we have set to the TreeItem ]?

Comment: I found it `setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());` In case any future user want to set the default graphic to the `TreeItem`

Answer (score 1):

I know that the OP uses Java 7 and JavaFX 2.2, but for people who use JavaFX 8, another elegant way goes like this:

```
PseudoClass PSEUDOCLASS1 = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pseudoclass1");
PseudoClass PSEUDOCLASS2 = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pseudoclass2");
PseudoClass PSEUDOCLASS3 = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pseudoclass3");

TreeView<MyTreeType> tree = new TreeView<>();
tree.setCellFactory(treeView -> new TreeCell<MyTreeType>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyTreeType item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_1, false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_2, false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_3, false);
        } else {
            setText(item.getText());
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_1, item.isFoo());
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_2, item.isBar());
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDOCLASS_3, item.isBazinga());
        }
    }
});
```

In your external style sheet, you do then

```
.tree-cell:pseudoclass1 {
   /* the way you want the cell styled if pseudo class 1 is active */
}

.tree-cell:pseudoclass2 {
   /* the way you want the cell styled if pseudo class 2 is active */
}

.tree-cell:pseudoclass3 {
   /* the way you want the cell styled if pseudo class 3 is active */
}
```

CSS pseudo classes are rather used to reflect a certain state, while CSS classes are used to reflect a certain static property. But in the end, it is rather a matter of taste.